# android version compatibility

Tags: java, android

The question is myapp sometimes run well and sometimes doesn't.I used ionic+cordova+angular to do it. It does not work at 5.0.1 version.
This is the logcat when i test with android studio
`07-28 15:55:19.894 9987-9987/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
07-28 15:55:19.894 9987-9987/? E/Zygote: v2
07-28 15:55:19.904 9987-9987/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-28 15:55:19.904 9987-9987/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-28 15:55:20.084 9987-9987/io.ionic.starter E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
07-28 15:55:20.164 9987-9987/io.ionic.starter E/chromium: [ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(258)] Failed to init browser shader disk cache.
07-28 15:55:20.194 9987-9987/io.ionic.starter E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
07-28 15:55:20.194 9987-10081/io.ionic.starter E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings`

Comment: This is my routes.js<br>

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/assetsPublic"),It should be show ,but now it was a blank page，Thx for your answer！

Comment: *what is your problem*?

Comment: when I install it ,it show nothing.

Comment: if the android version is 6.1，it show normal

Comment: `07-28 16:26:17.564 8089-8089/io.ionic.starter E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-28 16:26:17.884 8089-8089/io.ionic.starter E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`

Answer (score 0):

**ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --save**  Add this will be work.